# Generating random groups satisfying certain conditions

Tags: group-theory, random

I am trying to find a counterexample to a claim about groups.

I need a random generator (a program in any programming language, or an algorithm) which will generate a random group $G$ of any order such that:

- $G$ has a p-subgroup $P$ which is not a Sylow p-subgroup
- $G$ has a normal subgroup $N$ whose order is coprime with $|P|$

Is there any known work on generating random groups in general? The only way I see now is to create a multiplication table, check group axioms, check the properties I need. But this is  inefficient. I do not think I can every generate a group satisfying the above properties by simply trying all tables. Any thoughts?

Comment: Any finite groups is a subgroup of some symmetric group. If you take a language that can generate subgroups of the symmetric group (e.g. magma or GAP) you might be able to generate some examples (it is still inefficient though).

Comment: If you want to choose a group of order $n$ whose isomorphism class is uniformly distributed over all isomorphism types of groups of order $n$, then I think that is only even approximately possible if a complete list of isomorphism types is available. So there would be no problem for orders up to $2000$.

Comment: I am minded of Gordon Royle's quote: sometimes a couple of days enthusiatic programming can save you an hour's careful thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to write down a group with the desired properties; and, you should be able to see how to generalise this to provide infinitely many more examples.  Take $G = C_2^2\times C_3$, and $P = C_2$ and $N = C_3$.  The Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$ is $C_2^2$, $P$ is a non-Sylow $2$-subgroup, and $N$ - with order coprime to $2$ - is certainly normal in $G$ because $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Thanks. This approach helps to generate some subgroups. We can more elements to the direct product with orders coprime to 2 to get more groups.